# Jquery onclick change image - 3 Products holders

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

EDIT:

I would like to add another button so in total I have 3 buttons instead of 2. 
How can I do this ? I tried to add a product holder three but then if I click first button 1 and then button 3, both button have the same background image.

Preview: http://gyazo.com/6698586765626a57405f9232baaaf61f.gif

I have 3 buttons, When they click on one of them it changes the image.. So if user clicks on button 1, it changes image. Is the now clicks the button 2 in case he want to select this one button 1 image goes back to normal.

Website: http://productsgiveaway.com/iphone5s/

I would appreciate some help.

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".theImage img").click(function () {
        var a = $(this).parent().attr("id") == "product-holder1" ? "product-holder2" : "product-holder1";
        console.log(a);
        $(this).fadeOut();
        $("#" + a + " img").fadeIn()
    })
})
```

Comment: Thanks for edit Jason!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is pretty much there, but you need to remove the `!important` on the CSS from this line:

`img { display: block !important; }`.

It is over-riding the `display:none;` that later gets applied to that Select image when it fades out. If you change that to just `img {display: block}`, the affect works as I believe you're intending.

Comment: Haha I never though about that one, Thanks a lot Joseph! One high five to you!

Comment: There you go! Thanks for such a quick answer!

Comment: Hi how can I add 3 product-holders and still keep this effect?