# 3 product holders jquery onclick image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to add another button so in total I have 3 buttons instead of 2. How can I do this ? I tried to add a product holder three but then if I click first button 1 and then button 3, both button have the same background image.

Preview: http://gyazo.com/6698586765626a57405f9232baaaf61f.gif

New code(Doesn't work):

```
$(document).ready(function(){$(".theImage img").click(function(){
    var a=$(this).parent().attr("id")=="product-holder1"?"product-holder2"?"product-holder3":"product-holder1";
    console.log(a);
    $(this).fadeOut();
    $("#"+a+" img").fadeIn();
   });
});
```

I have 3 buttons, When they click on one of them it changes the image.. So if user clicks on button 1, it changes image. Is the now clicks the button 2 in case he want to select this one button 1 image goes back to normal.

Website: http://productsgiveaway.com/iphone5s/

I would appreciate some help.

Old code Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".theImage img").click(function () {
    var a = $(this).parent().attr("id") == "product-holder1" ? "product-holder2" : "product-holder1";
    console.log(a);
    $(this).fadeOut();
    $("#" + a + " img").fadeIn()
})
})
```

Comment: Previous thread, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19337824/jquery-onclick-change-image-3-products-holders

Sorry for double posting..

Comment: You should be able to delete this question if it was unintentionally posted

Comment: Hi! Yes but I edited my previous question will people still click it? I already got an answer on the question?

Comment: I added product-holder3 but doesnt work :)

     $(document).ready(function(){$(".theImage img").click(function(){var a=$(this).parent().attr("id")=="product-holder1"?"product-holder2"?"product-holder3":"product-holder1";console.log(a);$(this).fadeOut();$("#"+a+" img").fadeIn()})})

Comment: Please update your question. Don't put code in comments.

Comment: If its a new question thats similar to the old one just specify the differences in your original post and the new problem that is happening. Utilize the edit feature dont put code in the comments. Its a pain to read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your console when you're clicking on the images. The `product-holder#` is all messed up. This is your problem. I do now understand why youre setting the variable `a` like that. Try just using this....

`var a = $(this).parent().attr("id");`

What youre doing above is the same as saying....

```
if(id==product-holder1)
    a=product-holder2;
else
    a=product-holder1;
```

So youre really reversing them around and thats your problem. Just use the id attribute to get the id of the parent.

EDIT:

Try putting this in for me. Im not positive it will work but I want to see what it does

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".theImage img").click(function(){
        $(".theImage img").fadeIn(); //SPOT 1
        $(this).fadeOut();
    });
});
```

Glad to see it works. Heres whats happening... You set a background image to the continue picture and then put the select on top. So what you want to do is make sure that every select image is showing when you click it (SPOT 1) in code. Then you use the `$(this)` selector to get the image that you click and then just hide that. Which will then show the background image you have underneath. This will give you your desired effect. You were actually making it much more complicated than it had to be with pulling the ID's in.

Comment: It would, if you use `"`.

Comment: the if statement code doesnt have correct syntax I just wanted him to understand the point...

Comment: Okay I updated the javascript code and now its kinda working but it goes back to select?

Comment: #wumm Where do I need " ?

Comment: @DaveMikes hes talking about in the if statement... Setting those ids needs quotes around the product-holder string or else javascript will assume they are variables but thats not important to your code. I was using that as an example

Comment: Okay, I updated the code on the website as you see its reverting back to image 1 and not the click image?

Comment: @DaveMikes Yeah I see it im working on it now... Its pretty hard if I cant play with the code. I have a question though. Where are the continue images in the html?? Are they underneath it the select somehow?? It looks like when the selects are faded out, thats when the continue shows. Is this correct?

Comment: They are css styles. Display-block

Comment: @DaveMikes Look at my edit and try putting that in. If it works Ill explain it all to you.

Comment: Kierchon perfect! Let me upload it 2 secs..

Comment: @DaveMikes Awesome. I put an explanation in my post. Let me know if you have any questions